# Splitting data from an array and pulling specific data

Tags: c#, string, string-parsing

I think what i have to do is split and pull data to do the following:

I have created a class, with the following array and method getContactList.  I need to create a method getFirstNames() and return all the first names from the address book into the variable firstNames in a Test class and display them on the console.

```
class ContactList
{
    public String[] contactList = 
    { 
    "John, Smith, jsmith@nbcc.ca, (506) 555-1234", 
    "Frank, Sinatra, fsinatra@nbcc.ca, (506) 696-1234", 
    "Joan, Rivers, jrivers@nbcc.ca, (506) 696-5678", 
    "Freddy, Mercury, fmercury@nbcc.ca, (506) 653-1234", 
    "Freddy, Kruger, fkruger@nbcc.ca, (506) 658-1234"
    };

       public String[] getContactList()
    {

        return contactList;
    }


    public String getLastNames()
    {
        string lastnames = "";

        return lastnames;
    }


}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ContactList firstNames = new ContactList();
        Console.WriteLine(firstNames.getFirstNames());

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting hard-coded data in the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better design it this way:

```
class ContactList
{
string firstName, lastName, eMail, ContactNo;
//Properties (getters/setters for above attributes/fields
}

class ContactListHandler
{

public List<string> GetFirstNames(string[] contactsText)
{

List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in contactsText)

{
var x = contactsText.split(',');
stringList.Add(x[0]);
}

return stringList;
}

//and other functions
}

Main()
{
ContactListHandler cHandler = new ContactListHandler();
List<string> contactsString = cHandler.GetFirstNames(//your string variable containing the contacts);

foreach(string s in contactsString)
{
Console.WriteLine(s);
}
}
```

Yes it has increased code but only for once, now you can use it in an Object-oriented way for any string,etc.

Comment: @Talha Irfan, voting system is for the purpose of highlighting the usefulness of the answers, not for bring down someones answer for your own benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Yours isn't exactly the best approach, but to achieve what you want...
(assuming you want to separate the names by , )

```
public string getFirstNames(){
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
   foreach(var x in contactList){
       var tmp=x.Split(',');
       sb.Append(tmp[0]);
       sb.Append(",");
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: When trying to put "var" in my code in Visual Studio 2013, it doesnt let me. Is "var" an actual keyword in C#? Or is it to represent a data type?

Comment: When you use var, you need to also assign a value / reference to it, otherwise the compiler can't infer the type.
If the answer was useful, remember to upvote / mark as answer.

Comment: This definitely helps @Saverio  Thank you

Comment: Another related question is how can i get the usernames (everything before "@" in email) and a number of addresses contained in the address book ?  Greatly appreciated any help.

Comment: The Split method, returns an array which is made of the tokens divided by the separator of choice (',') in your case. If you want the email, you choose the token with index 2, the number with the index 3.
If you want to get the username, you can use the same strategy on the email address, choosing "@" as separator.

Comment: I was able to do that but unable to remove everything after the @

Comment: Once you have a whole email address in a variable, let's call it var tmpEmail, you can do var emailUsername=tmpEmail.Split('@')[0], to get the first token right away.

Comment: public String getUsernames()    
        {    
            StringBuilder usernames = new StringBuilder();    
            foreach (var x in contactList)    
            {    
                var tmp = x.Split(',');    
                //var emailUsername = tmp.Split('@')[0];    
                usernames.Append(tmp[2]);    
                usernames.Append("\n");    
            }    
            return usernames.ToString();    
        }

Comment: It's kind of hard to get it from the comment box but at a first glance, I think that inside the foreach you could do:
var userName=x.Split(',')[2].Split('@')[0]; 
to retrieve the username.

Comment: I tried that and all i got was s,s,r,m,k - it somehow deleted the first letter of the email address and only gave me the 2nd letter of the email address.

Comment: pastebin.com/eA18KdMH

Comment: In getUsernames, replace var tmp = x.Split(',');
                usernames.Append(tmp[2]); with usernames.Append(x.Split(',')[2].Split('@')[0]);

Comment: I tried what you said as it says and i get a red squiggly line under everything starting with x.split ... Error says method name expected

Comment: Are you using it in the foreach instruction in which is declared a var x?

Comment: Yes I am. I did exactly as you instructed

Comment: Please past again all your changed code, and I'll have a look at it tomorrow

Comment: Thanks @Saverio.  pastebin.com/c5WAa3yD

Comment: Looking at it (without trying it), I noticed there is an extra unneeded parenthesis after the first split and the second index is written with round parenthesis instead of squared ones. 
It should've been: usernames.Append(x.Split(',')[2].Split('@')[0]); but I see it's written as usernames.Append(x.Split(','))[2].Split('@')(0);

Comment: I am glad it finally works :) I see you've just joined our community. As a general rule of Stackoverflow, when you find a question or an answer interesting/helpful you can upvote it with the upward button on the side. On the flip side, if you find some answer / question wrong / silly, you should do the opposite downvoting it (downward button).

Comment: I tried but it says i need 15 to vote and i am only at 2

Answer (score 0):

It's working I checked :) good luck with your development

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
        // Just to hold data
        string[] data = new String[]{"John, Smith, jsmith@nbcc.ca, (506) 555-1234","Frank, Sinatra, fsinatra@nbcc.ca, (506) 696-1234","Joan, Rivers, jrivers@nbcc.ca, (506) 696-5678","Freddy, Mercury, fmercury@nbcc.ca, (506) 653-1234","Freddy, Kruger, fkruger@nbcc.ca, (506) 658-1234"};

        // Create new contact list object
        ContactList contacts = new ContactList(data);

        // Call our method
        contacts.PrintLastNames();

    }
}


public class ContactList
{
    // Declare properties
    // google C# getter setter
    private List<string> cList;
    public List<string> CList{
        get{ return cList; }
    }

    // Constructor
    public ContactList(string[] _contactList)
    {
        // When creating new instance, take array of contacts and put into list    
        this.cList = _contactList.ToList();
    }

    // This will print out the names
    public void PrintLastNames()
    {
        // Google lambda expression C# for more info on iteration
        // With each string in cList, split by comas and use the first element 
        this.cList.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x.Split(',')[0]));

        // Use this for last names
        //this.cList.ForEach( x => Console.WriteLine(x.Split(',')[1]));
    }

    // This will return names in list
    public List<string> GetLastNames()
    {
        // Google List Collection Generic C# for more info
        List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
        this.cList.ForEach( x => namesList.Add( x.Split(',')[0] ));

        return namesList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please mark as solved, and +1 to make it useful to other users.

Comment: how?  first time on here, do i just put "Solved, +1"  in comments?